# Extra space on sides of images in outlook when creating HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have been scouring the internet for around 2 days now and I can't find anything about an issue. I am facing with extra space on the **LEFT** and **RIGHT** side of images in Outlook desktop.

The extra space, affects the ability of my table/columns to be displayed side by side. If I shorten the width of any cell/row/table to the exact width of that space (circled in red in image) they suddenly pop in side by side. It is this particular little space I can't figure out how to remove. It is like there is a default value set somewhere on something I am unaware of.

Sorry about some images not being uploaded anywhere, these ones weren't really important.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUeF7.png) How it appears in every other email client.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sdfL.png) How it is appearing in outlook only.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  table[class=responsive] {
    width: 330px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  table[class=left] {
    width: 330px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  table[class=right] {
    width: 330px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  img {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

p {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

a {
  color: #333333;
}

a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

</head>

<body style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">

  <!-- CENTER TABLE -->
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">

        <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive">
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="10324612_ptgray.jpg" align="left" style="vertical-align: top; display:inline-block;"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#666666" height="50">
              <p style="text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><b>THE JULY ISSUE OF <em>PHYSICS TODAY</em> IS AVAILABLE</b><br></p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <td>
              <table class="left" width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                <tr border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                  <td border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVa1S.png" width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="vertical-align: top; display: block; max-width: 100%;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="right" width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px;">Advertisement</p>
                    <p style="color: #333333; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;">THERE'S NO ESCAPE: LEAK-TIGHT GAS PUMPS</p>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px;">KNF double-diaphragm, oil-free pumps are designed for transporting and evacuating costly, high purity, rare and/or dangerous gases. The back-up safety diaphragm ensures ultra-low leak rates of &#60;6×10&#94;-6 L/sec, while other safeguards
                      prevent contamination from external influences. Options available.</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
              <a href="#">
                <table class="left" width="438" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" height="287">
                      <p style="font-size: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">View the November Issue Online</p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="right" width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                  <tr>
                    <td><img src="pt-cover.jpg" style="vertical-align: top; display: block;"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <td>
              <table class="left" width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVa1S.png" width="220" height="220" style="vertical-align: top; display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="right" width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px;">WHITEPAPER</p>
                    <p style="color: #C8544B; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;">THERE'S NO ESCAPE: LEAK-TIGHT GAS PUMPS</p>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px;">KNF double-diaphragm, oil-free pumps are designed for transporting and evacuating costly, high purity, rare and/or dangerous gases. The back-up safety diaphragm ensures ultra-low leak rates of &#60;6×10&#94;-6 L/sec, while other safeguards
                      prevent contamination from external influences. Options available.</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-align: center;">
            <td>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B; font-size: 24px">Restoring sight with retinal prostheses</p>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B;">Author or Department</p>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- SPACER -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B; font-size: 24px">Large amplitude oscillatory shear: Simple to describe, hard to interpret</p>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B;">Author or Department</p>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- SPACER -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B; font-size: 24px">Who owns a scientist's mind?</p>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B;">Author or Department</p>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- SPACER -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B; font-size: 24px">Magnets separate mirror-image molecules</p>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B;">Author or Department</p>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- SPACER -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B; font-size: 24px">Concerns about aging plutonium drive need for new weapon cores</p>
                  <p style="border-left: 5px solid #C8544B;">Author or Department</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <td>
              <table class="left" width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVa1S.png" width="220" style="vertical-align: top; display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="right" width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px;">Advertisement</p>
                    <p style="color: #333333; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;">THERE'S NO ESCAPE: LEAK-TIGHT GAS PUMPS</p>
                    <p style="color: #000000; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px;">KNF double-diaphragm, oil-free pumps are designed for transporting and evacuating costly, high purity, rare and/or dangerous gases. The back-up safety diaphragm ensures ultra-low leak rates of &#60;6×10&#94;-6 L/sec, while other safeguards
                      prevent contamination from external influences. Options available.</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-align: center;">
            <td>
              <p><strong>Help desk information:</strong><br><br>If you need technical assistance, please do not reply to this automated email; <a href="http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/84311897/?cmd=file&file=visitorWantsToChat&site=84311897&byhref=1&SESSIONVAR!operator=admin&SESSIONVAR!skill=Default%20Ticket%20Skill&imageUrl=http://www.advancedpublishing.com/images/LivePerson">click here</a>.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <tr>
            <td height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-align: center;">
            <td>
              <p>This email has been sent to %%email%%. In case you are not able to click on the links above, please go to: <a href="#">http://physicstoday.advanced-pub.com</a></p>
              <p>Physics Today is published by the American Institute of Physics, One Physics Ellipse, College Park, MD. 20740. Send publication questions to <a href="mailto:pteditors@aip.org">pteditors@aip.org</a>. The information contained in this e-mail
                message is intended only for the personal use of the recipient(s). For Information on American Institute of Physics' Privacy Policy please click here. We appreciate your interest in our publication and encourage you to contact us with
                your comments or suggestions. Thank you!</p>
              <p>To unsubscribe, please <a href="#">click here</a>.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>


        </table>

        <!-- CENTER TABLE -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you were to please edit your code snippet such that the image links have `src` attributes with absolute URIs.

Comment: Take a look at this site, https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/ if the information in this article is correct, the solutions they give may help your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test and search, it not img's reason, might be table.
You could refer to the below code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="238" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:238px; color: #ffffff; width:238px;height: 40px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #f2f2f2;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="40" width="22" align="left">
                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                        <a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank">
                            <img height="40" src="ctaleftgrey.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" />
                        </a>
                    </p>
        </td>
        <td height="40" width="180" align="left">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="180" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; " valign="middle">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text goes here</a>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td height="40" width="36" align="left">
                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img height="40" src="ctarightgrey.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" />
                        </a>
                    </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</body>
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Outlook table spacing in HTML email - no usual tricks working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071608/outlook-table-spacing-in-html-email-no-usual-tricks-working)

[Table style border- outlook 2010 adds an extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015773/table-style-border-outlook-2010-adds-an-extra-space)

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to be the the one of the 5 elements the image was nested in, I just didn't know what attribute was the cause and I tried so many individual and combinations.

This fixed everything.

style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"